# Why is $n^{\pi (2)− \pi ()} ≤ {2 \choose }$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, combinations

A follow-up from a previous question I asked:  if $\pi ()$ counts the number of primes less than or equal to $n$ and $M = \pi (2 n)− \pi (n)$, i.e. the number of primes greater than $n$ but less than or equal to $2n$, then how can we explain why

$$n^{\pi (2n)− \pi (n)} \leq {2 \choose } ?$$

Comment: Since you know that there are exactly $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ primes $p$ with $n<p<2n$ and each such prime is a divisor of $\binom{2n}{n},$ and each divisor is bigger than $n.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need that for any prime $p$ with $n<p\leq 2n,$ you have that $p\mid \binom{2n}{n}.$

Since there are $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ distinct such primes, their product is more than $n^{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)}.$ But the product of these primes must divide $\binom{2n}{n}.$ So:

$$n^{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)}\leq \prod_{n<p\leq 2n} p\mid \binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: Nice answer. I came up with a messier analytic solution, but this is clean and to the point.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, this is usually a lemma on the way to an elementary proof of Bertrand's postulate (I believe),)so it was familiar to me.

Comment: In retrospect, this really gives just an upper bound of $\pi(2n)-\pi(n),$ The Bertrand postulate proof I've seen uses properties of the prime divisors of $\binom{2n}{n},$ but in more complicated ways.